# OnCompleted called inside zip

Tags: java, android, rx-java

```
Observable<List<Object1>> obs1 = getObservableList1().from({/*some code*/
}).map({/*some code*/}).toList({/*some code*/});

Observable<List<Object2>> obs2 = getObservableList2();

Observable.zip(obs1 , obs1, (res1, res2) -> {

//some more code block1

}).subscribe({

//some code after obs1 and obs2 
//some more code block2

});
```

I have situation when obs1 contains empty list and `zip.subscribe()` is never called. But I need just return empty `List` as `res1` and execute block1 and block2 like if the list from `obs1` have elements.

The question is how to skip `from().map().toList()` from `obs1` and return empty `List` as `res1`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what do you want to achieve? If you want to just execute some code after *both* the source Observables complete, use the following:

```
 Observable.merge(obs1 , obs2).doOnComplete(() -> {
    ....
 }).subscribe(...)
```

If instead you need to do something with the result list, but `obs2` is sometimes empty (no items), then you just need to set a default:

```
 Observable<List<Object2>> obs2 = getObservableList2()
         .defaultIfEmpty(Collections.emptyList());
```